# on new page and chapter title in an image

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I want the file to be as follows.
1-page first chapter in a different color
2. Insert the diamond in the title of Chapter
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\use[![enter image description here][1]][1]package{amsthm}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 \definecolor{myaqua}{rgb}{1,1,1}
  \definecolor{myaqua1}{rgb}{0,0.5,0.45}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
%\fancyhead{}
%\fancyfoot{}
%\fancyhead[R]{}
%\fancyfoot[C]{}
%\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
%\renewcommand \thechapter {\@tartibi\c@chapter}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{250\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \if@RTL\raggedleft\else\raggedright\fi \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip100\p@
      \fi
    \fi    
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 10\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter {titel }
%\pagecolor{myaqua1}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
\pagecolor{myaqua1}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
\newpage
\pagecolor{myaqua}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Re: Your suggested edit to my answer: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do there, but if you wish to show the final (or intermediate) result, it's probably more sensible to edit your original post (by appending the new information, not removing the start, because then people won't understand anymore what it was all about) instead of editing (and removing) most of mine, unless that was accidental. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually work with the `memoir` class, so I'm can't say whether redefining `\@makechapterhead` is the right way to do this, but as for the aesthetics themselves, here's my attempt via Ti*k*Z.

[image: result]

I did encounter a bit of a weird thing: `\@chapapp` does not work inside the `tikzpicture` environment, so for now, it's hardcoded in the `\@chapterdesignator` macro (I hope I picked the right thing to put in there as I do not speak or read Persian; if not, I reckon you can fix it easily enough). Maybe one of the LaTeX magicians around here can tell us why this is and has a clean fix; this one is of course not very nice.

Of course, the code could be further optimized, parametrized, tweaked etc., but it should get the basic idea across.

**NOTE**: Must be compiled twice to get the picture placement correct, due to the `remember picture,overlay` for the `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
  \definecolor{myaqua}{rgb}{1,1,1}
  \definecolor{myaqua1}{HTML}{21bdbe}
  \definecolor{myaqua2}{HTML}{19bfe0}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand \thechapter {\@tartibi\c@chapter}
\def\@chapterdesignator{فصل}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[myaqua2] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \draw[white,very thick] ($(current page.south west) + (0mm,30mm)$)
            -- ++(150mm,0mm) node[very thick,rotate=45,draw=white,fill=myaqua2] {};
        \draw[white,very thick] 
            ($(current page.south west) + (20mm,40mm)$)
            -- ++(  0mm, 30mm)
            -- ++( 20mm, 20mm);

        \path[very thick,draw=white,fill=myaqua1] 
            ($(current page.south west) + (55mm,85mm)$)
            -- ++(40mm, 40mm)
            -- ++(-40mm, 40mm)
            -- ++(-40mm,-40mm)
            -- ++( 40mm,-40mm) --cycle;

        \draw[white!80!myaqua2]
            ($(current page.south west) + (75mm,105mm)$)
            -- ++(  2mm,-2mm)
            -- ++( 22mm,22mm)
            -- ++(-22mm,22mm)
            -- ++( -2mm,-2mm);

        \draw[very thick,white]
            ($(current page.south west) + (105mm,135mm)$)
            -- ++(40mm,-40mm)
            -- ++(70mm,0mm);

        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne
            \if@mainmatter
                \node[text=white] 
                    at ($(current page.south west) + (55mm,125mm)$)
                    {\huge\bfseries \@chapterdesignator\space \thechapter};
            \fi
        \fi

        \node[align=right,anchor=west] at 
            ($(current page.south west) + (60mm,40mm)$)
            {\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \cleardoublepage
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{عنوان فصل }
سلام خوبی 

ممنونم تو خوبی 



\section{sallam}
در این بخش داریم 
\newpage
f
\newpage
\end{document}
```